# How can I use same MySql database for several computers on local network

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, wamp

Need Help.

I made a vb.net project for medical clinic, it is already finished ,my project using MySql database, the application need to be connected to local network on 3-5 windows computers at the same time and share data(use same sql database at same time). i used wamp server while i was developing, but my problem is, i dont know how to make all computers use same sql database at same time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Plesae refer to this page to help you formulate a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask but for now: what have you tried? what is not working? what errors do you get?...

Comment: I did not get any errors.I just need to know how to make mysql database accessible in local network. I mean 3-5 windows computers can use same database(modified,select,insert,delete...data )

Comment: I mean is it possible to install wamp server to one windows computer and another computers can access it through the web?or any alternatives solutions

Comment: You should use one central DB, you application also on a central server and all your users (clients, browsers, etc) pointing to it.  In fact, this is pretty common.  Called three-tier architecture (server-database-client) with the client being a browser (I presume)

Comment: Btw, being a medical app, I will strongly suggest you secure your app and the database *properly*.

Comment: Can you explain me a more detailed. im not really good at network,sql and servers.Thank you:)

Comment: I am sorry but this is not the place for a tutorial.  You will want to hire someone to do it properly or follow a few tutorials online

Comment: Here, let me Google that for you: http://bit.ly/1x36KuE

Comment: Check this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/123012/set-up-wamp-server-to-run-on-lan) and  [another link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/263668-connecting-to-a-remote-databasemysql-on-lan-and-vbnet/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set up mysql for local lan(i don't know if it's needed or it is open to network by default) and then on other computers you have to connect to mysql server running on this computer via a static ip.
I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797946/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-using-vb-net-2010) might help you.

as mentioned it might not immediately work because of some firewall blocking issue or other network privilege problems.