# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to connect to mysql database through vb application. When I'm using server as `localhost` it connects. But when I'm using IP address - `192.168.1.112` it's giving error - `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts`

Working connection string

```
server=localhost; database=gm; userid=root; password=root;
```

Not working connection string

```
server=192.168.1.112; database=gm; userid=root; password=root;
```

Error Screen print 
[image]
I've ran the following query in mysql to grant all privileges -

```
grant all privileges on gm.* to 'root'@'192.168.1.112' identified by 'root'; 
flush privileges;
```

But Still not get it connected.This is almost same question as - [Connect to remote MySQL database using VB.NET 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797946/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-using-vb-net-2010). But it seems that it wasn't answered there as well. Please help.

**Update:**

When I turn off firewall of the computer, it works fine.

Comment: did you try see if the firewall or antivirus blocks the port? did you check your box ports?

Comment: Is '192.168.1.112' the ip of the machine you're connecting from ? Or is that the ip of the database ?

Comment: The db is installed in the machine whose ip address is 192.168.1.112.

Comment: Also, I tried to open port 3307 (through which I can connect with my separate php application) But it didn't work as well.