# VB.NET connection to MySQL Add Model

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to .NET. I am trying to use a code example from the first person that posted a response, here: [Connect to remote MySQL database using VB.NET 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797946/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-using-vb-net-2010)

I would like to instantiate the MySqlVB model object but when I add the following code into the controller, I get a not found error. I don't know how to resolve this.

The error is: Warning   1   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

What I need is to run a MySQL query and to return the dataset to the controller. Can someone show me how to do this, please?

I'm using VB 2010 Express to do this.

This is the controller

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PrintBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBtn.Click
        Dim data As New MySqlVB

        With data
            If .Connection Then
                MessageBox.Show("Database Conneted.")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(.ErrorMessage)
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

And this is my model object

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class MySqlVB
    Private _connection As New MySqlConnection
    Private _errormessge As String
    Private _servername As String = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    Private _databasename As String = "testdb"
    Private _userid As String = "theuser"
    Private _password As String = "thepass"

    Public WriteOnly Property ServerName() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _servername = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property DatabaseName() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _databasename = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property UserID() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _userid = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property Password() As String
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _password = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ErrorMessage() As String
        Get
            Return _errormessge
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function Connection() As Boolean
        Try
            _connection.ConnectionString = "Server=" & _servername & ";Port=3306;Database=" & _databasename & ";User ID=" & _userid & ";Password=" & _password & ""
            _connection.Open()
            If _connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                _connection.Close()
                Return True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            _errormessge = ex.Message
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: it is better to look for MySqlCommand and vb net this brings a lot of examples . But to your problem, you have a project, you downloaded mysql connector and added the dll as reference. After that you added a new class MySqlVB, and changed the variables nto fit your mysql server then put your code into your Form. So that works fine and where exactly do you get your error?

Comment: @nbk, thanks. I'll look into that. To answer your question, yes, I have a project and MySQL connector (ODBC) was already installed on the machine where VB resides. I have not added a reference though and I'm not sure if I need to or not. I have also used the variables in the controller but the error still remains. The error is being generated from the controller file.

Comment: `I have not added a reference though and I'm not sure if I need to or not.`  You need to.

Comment: Why ODBC? Why not MySql native provider?

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel building the connection string. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.htm

Comment: the MySqlVB class makes a connection with the server. he only need e the reference, but i repeated all steps only if someelse needs help and missed a step

Comment: @nbk What is e in you last comment? Steps to do what?

Comment: @LarsTech Why does Nan need to add a reference to the ODBC connector? He seems to be using MySql.Data.MySqlClient.

Comment: @Mary They need a reference to the MySql library — has nothing to do with the ODBC thing.

Comment: You can download Visual Studio 2019 community for free if you are a student or individual developer. VB 2010 is nine years old, an eternity in tech. Of course, if this is what your employer is providing, you are stuck.

Comment: Your message box reports "Database Connected" but it is not. You closed the connection directly after you opened it. Also, connections need to be disposed. Check `Using...End` Using blocks.

Comment: When you follow my steps since  But to your problem etc. you will have a program that open a connection when ou click the button. After the established connection you add a mysqlcommand with select your table and the rest you can find. The problem from the fist post that it misses the reference.

Comment: @Mary, thanks for all the help. I'm stuck on VS 2010 as this is what my employer uses and there is no interest in upgrading at this time, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have fixed your reference to MySql.Data.MySqlClient I think your class could use some work.

```
Public Class DataAccess

    Private ConnectionString As String

    Public Sub New(UserName As String, Password As String)
        Dim builder As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder With {
            .Server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            .Database = "testdb",
            .UserID = UserName,
            .Password = Password
        }
        ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
        Debug.Print(ConnectionString) 'just to see what the builder created
    End Sub

    Public Function TestConnecion() As Boolean
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Try
                cn.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message) 'just to see what is wrong with connection
                Return False
            End Try
        End Using
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Function GetData() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From SomeTable")
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class
```

Assuming you have a DataGridView to display data and 2 text boxes for user id and password, you can use your class in your form like this.

```
Private Sub FillGrid()
    Dim daClass As New DataAccess(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)
    Dim dt = daClass.GetData
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Of course you will need to add error handling. Also you need to salt and hash passwords. Plain text passwords should never be stored.

Comment: Thank you Mary. I'm brand new with this language. Thank you for the help!