# How to connect vb.net 2012 into database on other computer

Tags: phpmyadmin, architecture, xampp

I want to develop a voting system. For that purpose, I want to connect a client computer with a server using `xampp myphpadmin`. Could you please give me idea how to connect a client to a server database?

Comment: take a look a this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797946/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-using-vb-net-2010

Comment: or this http://www.phpsync.com/2016/08/vbnet-setup-connecting-to-remote-mysql.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to remote MySQL database using VB.NET 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797946/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-using-vb-net-2010)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - for the current question, I corrected your typos and grammar, as well as the tags.

Comment: I also have connection with apache port of server i also try mysql port of server but still it doesnt work...